# Webdriver doesn't open an upload window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to click on an element, which opens an windows model (choose a file..).

When I try to click on this button, no upload button is opened (But when I click on it manually it opens. Also, I see WebDriver success to find the element - the button is marked, but no window is opened.)

I try the next, none of them works:

```
1. currentPopup.click();

2. new Actions(driver).click(currentPopup).perform();

3. JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", currentPopup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not click that button. Selenium does not popup the windows open file.

The work around is

```
driver.findElement(By.id("UploadElementID")).sendKeys("<absolutePathToFile>");
```

UploadElementID is the id of that element (input type="file") and in sendKeys you have to specify the absolute path of the content you want to upload (Image,video etc). Selenium will do the rest for you

Comment: It still doesn't work. Just to make clear: When I click on currentPopup it opens a 'File Upload' window when I can choose any file in my PC. Then I choose a file, and another window is opened (in my Web page), which show me the process of the uploading and other options. So I try to do: 'currentPopup.sendKeys("C:\\11\\xtl.html")', as you say, and nothing happens (I don't see the window of the processing..).

Comment: Do you have any element like <input type="file"> . If yes please use the above code on this(i mean use this input and use sendKeys on it) instead of button.